# Keep top 10% of observations across multiple dataframes without losing data in R

Tags: r, subset, dplyr, rbind

I'm having trouble rbind.fill'ing multiple dataframes while subsetting them at the same time. My general data frames are a 1x(6000->60,000), where the single row is a given Memorial (Lincoln Memorial) and the columns are every single word pair in every single review on Yelp and Trip Advisor, with the number being how many times the word pair appears.

I'd like to reduce it to the top 10% of word pairs, while not losing the chance that a bottom 90% in one was in the top 10% of the other.

```
four_score = c(60)
seven_years = c(100)
dataframe1 <- data.frame(four_score,seven_years)


seven_years = c(10)
our_fathers = c(40)
dataframe2 <- data.frame(seven_years,our_fathers)

four_score = c(100, 10)
our_fathers = c(NA, 40)
goal = (data.frame(four_score,our_fathers))
goal$dfName <- c("Dataframe1", "DataFrame2")
```

That's the goal, where I've taken the most used word pair (top 10%) from each DF (four_score=100, our_fathers=40) but also been able to fill in four_score=10 (which is bottom 90% in DF2, but because it was top 10% in DF1, it fills in).

So far, my extremely messy code proceeds as follows:

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
four_score = c(60)
seven_years = c(100)
dataframe1 <- data.frame(four_score,seven_years)
dataframe1 <- data.frame(t(dataframe1))
dataframe1$Words <- row.names(dataframe1)
colnames(dataframe1)[1] <- "Count"
dataframe1 = dataframe1[order(-dataframe1$Count),]
row.names(dataframe1)<- NULL
dfName = "dataframe1"
dataframe1  <-cbind(dataframe1,dfName)
melted_df1 <- melt(dataframe1, id=c("dfName", "Words"), measure="Count", variable.name="test")

seven_years = c(10)
our_fathers = c(40)
dataframe2 <- data.frame(seven_years,our_fathers)
dataframe2 <- data.frame(t(dataframe2))
dataframe2$Words <- row.names(dataframe2)
colnames(dataframe2)[1] <- "Count"
dataframe2 = dataframe2[order(-dataframe2$Count),]
row.names(dataframe2)<- NULL
dfName = "dataframe2"
dataframe2  <-cbind(dataframe2,dfName)
melted_df2 <- melt(dataframe2, id=c("dfName", "Words"), measure="Count", variable.name="test")

merged_melt <- rbind.fill(melted_df1, melted_df2)
merged_melt <- data.table(merged_melt)

so_close <- merged_melt[order(value, decreasing = TRUE), head(.SD, n = ceiling(.N/10)), by = dfName] %>%
  dcast.data.table(dfName ~ value)
```

However, that doesn't address the real issue -- finding that J=10 in the second data frame and filling it in. Is there something with %in% that I need after the fact?

Comment: Sorry I'm not getting this at all. Your `dataframe1` and `dataframe2` have each 1 row and two columns. `goal` has 2 rows and 2 columns. Top 10% of what? How is that defined?

Comment: Yeah I don't have any idea what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit it a bit more. Try and make it more clear.... It was just an example. Basically, I have many dataframes of a single memorial (the one row) with every two word combination across all of the review online about the given memorial (see edit, "four_score") with the # being how many times this two word combination has appeared across all of the reviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a process that picks the top x% rows and extracts the correspondings letters. Then goes back to the datasets and finds the rows that include those letters. In this way you'll bring up all info for letters that belong in x% in one dataset but not in other datasets.

The moment you create your 2 melted datasets try this:

```
# combine all your melted datasets
df_full = rbind(melted_df1, melted_df2)


df_full %>%
  group_by(dfName) %>%                               # for each dataset
  do(.[order(-.$value),][round(nrow(.)*0.5),]) %>%   # get the top 50% after ordering by value
  ungroup() %>%
  select(Letters) %>%                                # keep the letters you found
  distinct() %>%                                     # keep distinct letters (avoid using a letter multiple times)
  inner_join(df_full, by="Letters") %>%              # join back info from initial table
  dcast(dfName~Letters)                              # reshape


    #       dfName  d   j
    # 1 dataframe1 NA 100
    # 2 dataframe2 40  10
```

Comment: Oh my god. Thank you so much! That makes sense. As I was posting this I had discovered a question that had something with %in% but I couldn't conceptualize how to do it.

But yes, I do have more datasets (~40). Would I need to make it a function and lapply?

Comment: You'll need to be able to make a melted version of each dataset and then rbind them in one big dataset. Then I'll send you a code that will take care of the rest. I'll update my answer. Check with this simple example first to see how this works.

Comment: I changed the second call a little bit and it worked perfectly! Thanks for your help.

Full <- Full_List_Melted %>%

  dplyr::group_by(MonumentName) %>%  

  dplyr::do(.[order(.$value),]) %>%

  dplyr::do(utils::head(., "value", n = floor(nrow(.)/10)))%>%

  ungroup() %>%

  select(Bigram) %>%      

  distinct() %>%           

inner_join(Full_List_Melted, by="Bigram") %>%     

  dcast(MonumentName~Bigram, value.var="value")